# Probability to get a chocolate snowman or a chocolate reindeer

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, law-of-large-numbers

$N\in \mathbb{N}$ christmas presents will be distributed. In every gift there is additional either a chocolate snowman or a chocolate reindeer. It will be independent of each other and with the same probability of giving out gifts with a chocolate snowman or chocolate reindeer. So let $X_1, \ldots  , X_n$ be independent and Bernoulli-distributed with probability of success $p =\frac{1}{2}$. The event $\{X_j = 1\}$ means that in the $j$th present there is a chocolate reindeer. Let $a_n$ be the probability that at least 60% of the $n$ gifts distributed contains a chocolate reindeer.

(a) Calculate $a_{10}$ explicitly. Enter intermediate steps.

(b) Use the inequality $\displaystyle{P\left [\left |\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j-p\right |\geq \epsilon\right ]\leq \frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2}}$ from Bernoulli's weak law of large numbers, to estimate $a_{100}$. Does it hold $a_{100}<a_{10}$ ?

(c) Determine $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n}$.

$$$$

What exactly does $a_n$ mean? Is it the probability $P\left [X_1, \ldots , X_n\geq 0.6\cdot n\right ]$ ?

Comment: $P(a_n\geq 0.6)\Leftrightarrow P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100} X_i\geq 0.6\cdot n \right)\Leftrightarrow P\left(\frac1n\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^{100} X_i\geq 0.6\right)$ // So it is the sum.

Comment: Is it the sum till $100$ or till $n$ ? @callculus42

Comment: It depdends on the question. If n=100 then it is $100$. So you can replace $n$ by $100$ at my comment et vice versa.

Comment: So in geneal you mean that we have $$P(a_j\geq 0.6)\Leftrightarrow P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i\geq 0.6\cdot j \right)\Leftrightarrow P\left(\frac{1}{j}\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i\geq 0.6\right)$$ right? So in (a) we have $$a_{10}= P\left(\frac{1}{10}\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i\geq 0.6\right)$$ Is that correct so far? @callculus42

Comment: Yes, if you mean that $j=n$. You don´t have to distinguish between the indices $$P(a_{10}\geq 0.6)\Leftrightarrow P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} X_i\geq 0.6\cdot 10 \right)\Leftrightarrow P\left(\frac{1}{10}\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} X_i\geq 0.6\right)$$ If $n=100$, then replace $10$ by $100$.

Comment: To calculate that do we use the formula $$P[|\overline{X}-\mu|\geq \epsilon]\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}$$ ? @callculus42

Comment: So do we have to use the weak law of large numbers? @callculus42

Comment: The expected value of $X_i$ is $\mu=E[X_i]=p=\frac{1}{2}$ and the variance is $\sigma^2=\text{Var}(X_i)=p\cdot (1-p)=\frac{1}{4}$. So we get $$P[|\overline{X}-\mu|\geq \epsilon]\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}\Rightarrow P\left [\left |\overline{X}-\frac{1}{2}\right |\geq\epsilon\right ]\leq\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{10\cdot \epsilon^2}\Rightarrow P\left [\overline{X}\geq \epsilon+\frac{1}{2}\right ]\leq \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{10\cdot \epsilon^2}$$ For $\epsilon=0.1$ we get $$P\left [\overline{X}\geq 0.6\right ]\leq\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{10\cdot 0.1^2}\Rightarrow P\left [\overline{X}\geq 0.6\right ]\leq 2.5$$

Comment: This cannot be correct, can it? @callculus42

Comment: At b) isn´t $n=100$, instead of $10$? Otherwise I agree to you. And it fails for $n=10$.

Comment: What I have done was for (a), not for (b) . Do we have to do something else for (a)? Ah because it is asked for explicitly? So how do we calculate the probability there? @callculus42

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i$ is binomial distributed with $p=1/2$ and $n=10$. And at least $60\%$ is $\geq 0.6\cdot 10=6$. Therefore $$a_{10}=\sum\limits_{x=6}^{10}\binom{10}{x} \cdot \left( \frac12 \right)^{x}\cdot \left( \frac12 \right)^{10-x}= \left( \frac12 \right)^{10} \cdot \sum\limits_{x=6}^{10}\binom{10}{x}$$

Comment: Ah ok! So we get then at (b) $a_{100}\leq 0.25<0.376953\approx a_{10}$. @callculus42

Comment: Thank you for your help!! :-) @callculus42